# VB2010 Regular Expression

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox and a search button in my vb 2010 application. I want to get the user input and check if it contains any of the words in my list (cell, membrane, biology, animal, plant etc). Please I need the Regex Pattern.

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for that. A simple IF will suffice.

Comment: People won't write your code where. Show what you've tried and we'll give you advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the list you've given, you can use a Regex similar to the following:

```
^(cell|membrane|biology|animal|plant)$
```

To test you Regex pattern, you can head over to regexpal.com

But I would recommend putting all your words in an array and then do the checking, instead of using Regex since it's not some pattern you're matching against; but against specific words.

Answer (score 1):

[No Regex needed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html), this will do just fine.

```
Dim myInput as string
myInput = myControl.value

if (myInput="cell") or (myInput="membrane) or (myInput="biology) or... THEN
    'do something
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need regex to do that. If you want to check if it **contains** any of given words:

```
Dim input = "biology is good"
Dim words = New String() { "cell", "membrane", "biology", "animal", "plant" }
Dim contains = words.Any(Function(s) input.Contains(s))
```